# Cannot see new environmental variable from cmd

Tags: python, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm new to **dotenv** library and currently trying to use it for setting environmental variables in my python script.

I can successfully load the parameter in the code. Out of curiosity, I tried to find this newly loaded variable from CMD, but it isn't listed there.

Can anyone explain how is `load_dotenv` working? My understanding was that `load_dotevn` actually loads these parameters to system variables and then we are reading from system using `os` library?

Below code prints correct token.

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os

load_dotenv('.env')
token = os.environ.get("TUTORIAL_BOT_TOKEN")
print(token)
```

I assumed if I typed `set` in widnows cmd, it would list all environmental variables including the new one I just loaded. But its missing from the list.

Comment: I think you should reset your computer so the changes in the environmental variables will be updated.

Comment: hey @TDG thanks for the reply! what do you mean by reset? if I restart the cmd this variables should be deleted by definition right?

Comment: All that I know is that whenever I had to update the PATH variable for example, I had to restart my PC in order to get it updated.

Comment: Environment variables are private to each process. In other words, changing the env vars for process A does not change them for process B.